# Cannot Find Module Error for Truffle-contract

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-contract

Error:-

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './truffle-contract.min.js'
    at c (web3.min.js:1)
    at c (web3.min.js:1)
    at index.html:27

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./truffle-contract.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test For blockchain</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>    
        var Web3 = require("web3");
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined')
        { 
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://shivansh.blockchain.azure.com:3200/######")); 
        }
        //wb = new Web3(web3);
        //var HelloBlockchain = artifacts.require("HelloBlockchain");
        console.log("test");


        let contract = require('./truffle-contract.min.js')
        let HelloWorld = contract(require('./build/contracts/HelloBlockchain.json'))

        HelloWorld.setProvider(web3);
        HelloWorld.deployed().then(contract => {
        return contract.getMessage()
        }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have truffle-contract.min.js file in the same location as you are providing in your code i.e.,

> src="./truffle-contract.min.js"

Comment: It is in the correct place.

Comment: Can you show me the directory structure(including this file) of your project?

Comment: I can't since i have deleted the project as it was just for testing making a simple blockchain but I am sure that the minified truffle contract file was in the root folder.